# Passing Objects by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, object

**(I did not find the answer I was looking for but I figure it out my self so I want to try answering my own Question for someone else who may have it in the future)**

How can I pass an object to a non-Class function and change its data?
For example

class Foo{} has a private int x = 5 and I want to change it to 10 with out entering the changeValue function from the class directly but use a non-Class function to call this function.

Answer (score 0):

So if your code looks something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void changeValue(int val) { x = val; }
private:
    int x;
}
```

And you want to change the x outside the changeValue method, all you need to do is add function you want to change it in as a friend to Foo class. So for example, for this to work:

```
void g(Foo& foo) {
   foo.x = 10;
}
```

You must add this line to your Foo class:

```
friend void g(Foo& foo);
```

Declaring something inside the class as a friend allows that function/class to access private members and methods.

Comment: I posted an answer, this works for me, I do not know if it is right or not, could you check it?

Comment: Well after looking at your solution I don't see how that can work. If I'm right  ,inside the changeVal function when creating test2, it is created by copy so test2.change(num) won't change anything inside test.

Comment: When you declare something as private it shoudn't be accessible outside the ways you decide for it to be accessible (f.e. declaring outside functions as friends).

Answer (score -1):

Let's say we have

```
class Foo{
private:
    int x;
public:
    change(int y){
        x = y;
    }
}
```

and we want the function

```
void changeVal(Foo test, int num);
```

to change the X instead of

```
Foo::change(int y);
```

we would give our changeVal function the address of the object

```
int main(){
    Foo test;
    changeVal(&test, 5);   
}
```

then we are going to create changeVal and make a pointer object to hold the address of our original object

```
void changeVal(Foo* test, int num){
    ...
}
```

and in the body we need to create a third object to take the value of the original object so we give it the address we stored in the "Foo* test" and change the value of the new object with the address of the original so we are changing the original instead of a copy

```
void changeVal(Foo* test, int num){
    Foo test2 = &test;
    test2.change(num);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be more of a clarification to the question, than a complete answer. However, it's still not quite clear what you're asking. Perhaps, 
delete this question, collect everything into a new one (with working code), and highlight which part you're unsure about.